Apolloclient graphql query data and previous is undefined when loading is true
we are using @graphql-codegen to create hooks for our queries. We have a framework-query-hook called useFrameworkQuery, which contains important framework data such as viewport. The idea here is that framework data should be saved in the cache so that when we call useFrameworkQuery we can get important frameworkData.
but we have a weird issue where both previousData and data gets undefined when loading is true
this is the code that gets run repeatedly:
  const {
    data: frameworkData,
    error: frameworkError,
    loading: frameworkLoading,
    previousData,
  } = useFrameworkQuery({
    variables: {
      url: relativeUrl,
    },
  });
  console.log(
    'url:' + relativeUrl,
    frameworkData,
    previousData,
    'loading:' + frameworkLoading,
  );

we have a lot of logic and many components will run this exact code, but for a brief second under loading the previousData gets reset to undefined? and then later both get value. In my opinion, this shouldn't happen as the params for the query did not change so the results shouldn't either. This is the results of the console.logs after it has been run by different components (but still same params):
url:/7339260_F490/ undefined {framework: {…}} loading:true
url:/7339260_F490/ undefined {framework: {…}} loading:true
url:/7339260_F490/ undefined undefined loading:true
url:/7339260_F490/ undefined undefined loading:true
url:/7339260_F490/ {framework: {…}} {framework: {…}} loading:false

this causes our components to have an initial moment with no data causing undesired layoutshifts. Has this maybe anything to do with that the component that uses this hook is being mounted later?
For context: we're using NextJS, ApolloClient, codegen, SSR, and CSR
